# Spotfire: How to write SQL in Data Functions?

Tags: spotfire, terr

I have been trying to write a SQL in TERR in Data Function Window of Spotfire.
I have 2 tables in Spotfire (Teradata and Xls). I have to join the both on common columns (left) and then perform an aggregation.
I pulled the column that i needed from the xls into the teraData Table via Insert>>Columns option.
Now the sql that I want to run is:
"SELECT prod,sub_prod,year,month,week,count(id)/avg(rate) cnt 
FROM ip1
group by prod,sub_prod,year,month,week"

When I just say
op1 <- sqldf("SELECT prod,sub_prod,year,month,week,count(id)/avg(rate) cnt 
              FROM ip1
              group by prod,sub_prod,year,month,week")
It throws an error.
"TIBCO Spotfire Statistics Services returned an error: 'Error in library(sqldf) : there is no package called 'sqldf''"

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Subro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have statistic service installed for deployment...https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-spotfire-statistics-services-7-5-0

- Install the sqldf package: http://admin.viewcentral.com/events/uploads/TIBCO/Install-R-Packages_v65.pdf
- Restart the professional client
- Import the package in the Register Data Runctions window
- Run your script

This should resolve your error.

Comment: Does Spotfire come installed with the TERR packages.
As I am using the server login based client where in I have to enter my creds and only then does the client allow me to do any development activites

Comment: You have to install Spotfire Statistics Services

Comment: https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-spotfire-statistics-services-7-5-0

Comment: Found that sqldf was not installed. Sorted it.

library(sqldf)
op1 <- sqldf("SELECT Prod_parnt,prodct_grop,year,month,week,
count(distinct id) as prd_cnt,
Sum(Count(distinct id))
over (partition by modlty,prodct_grop order by year,month,week
rows between 12 preceding and current row) as cumu_prd_cnt,
avg(rate) as sal_rate
FROM ip1
group by Prod_parnt,prodct_grop,year,month,week")
Without the cumu_prd_cnt field the code works.
When I add that it gives me :
""TIBCO Spotfire Statistics Services returned an error: 'Error: error in statement: near &quot;(&quot;: syntax error'."

Comment: @Subro  so it was the package installation as I suggested. Please consider accepting this answer for future people who may encounter the same error. Then I would open a new question for the SYNTAX issue. 

Comment: I'll open the question and paste the link here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477963/spotfire-syntax-issue-or-window-functions-not-allowed
Question for the Syntax issue