# Spotfire : Syntax issue or Window functions not allowed?

Tags: spotfire, sqldf, terr

I am using Data functions in Spotfire.
I have the sqldf package installed.
Here is the query:

```
#Package to run sqls
library(sqldf)
#Input data frame
op1 <- sqldf("SELECT Prod_parnt,prodct_grop,year,month,week,
count(distinct id) as prd_cnt,
Sum(Count(distinct id))
over (partition by modlty,prodct_grop order by year,month,week
rows between 12 preceding and current row) as cumu_prd_cnt,
avg(rate) as sal_rate
FROM ip1
group by Prod_parnt,prodct_grop,year,month,week")
```

The error I am facing:

"TIBCO Spotfire Statistics Services returned an error: 'Error: error in statement: near "(": syntax error'."

Now the point to note here is that when I remove the Window function statement i.e cumu_prd_cnt field; the code works fine.

Need your help.

Comment: I've never seen `week rows between 12 preceding and current row` before... what does this part of your partition do?

Comment: Any feed back subro?

Comment: Essentially what this does is adds value from the previous 12 rows to the current row. I.e cumulative value restricted to previous 12 rows + current row.

Comment: What's the back end database @Subro ? SQL Server, MySQL, etc

Comment: Backend is Teradata. When I run this query directly on the developer/Assistant; it gives me the result. Of course I put in the proper table name and all. But when I run this in TERR. Well thats the reason I posted it here

Comment: Any updates on this folks?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't figure it out. You can post here though and one of the developers will be sure to answer. I used to answer there a lot but I'm not a big fan of their site: https://community.tibco.com/

Comment: I added there in parallel of creating post here. But no reply there either